# Using a value in array as index

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON string turned into an array.

It's a list of devices, each with name, status, etc and a unique reference named `ref`.

I can access the first device in my array with

```
echo $json_array_a[Devices][0][ref]
```

and it will return the correct ref for that device (being 11).

I would like to change my array to use the ref as the index so I would get the name of the same device by:

```
echo $json_array_a[Devices][11][name]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: This can be done by modifiying a script.

Comment: You will need to modify the structure of your array to do that.

Comment: Yes I need to modify the structure - thats what I'm looking for a way to do

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP documentation on array functions?

Comment: I have, and have tryed out various way, but I cant get it to work - I only go to SO when I am truely stuck. I do believe I need a "foreach function" to do the trick, but cant get it configured right

Comment: Please post your code in the future--people are much more likely to help if it looks like you have made an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Plus, it gives context for the query, rather than just a line or two to try to work out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to:

```
$new_array = array(Devices => array());
foreach ($json_array_a[Devices] as $value) {
    $new_array[Devices][$value[ref]] = $value;
}
```

Now `$new_array` should contain the array with indexes as you want.

Be aware though, if any of your refs are repeated then only the last one appearing in the original array will appear in the new array as it will overwrite any previous value.

Also, you use ref / name / Devices without any quotes - I've kept things the same here but I'm presuming that really those are strings and as such should be enclosed in quotes as 'ref' / 'name' / 'Devices'?

Comment: The strings should be quoted, yes.

Comment: That did it! The ref is unique always. Now I need to make the load of the json and the reindexing recurring, and update 50+ div's with the values... I know this cannot fir in this question, but I forsee I need more help :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function getDeviceName($devices,$index)
{
  $ref = $devices[$index]['ref'];
  return $devices[$ref]['name'];
}
```

Give it a try. Oh, you use it like this:

```
echo getDeviceName($json_array_a['Devices'],0);
```

calling something `$json_array_a` is not a way to program. The name of the array should reflect its content, not how it was created. I've tried to do it correctly in the function.

Comment: I get your point about the naming, and you are right. New naming is $devices_a (I keep the a to remind me that this is an array). So basically what I want to do is to loop through $devices_a and get a $reindexed_devices_a